# Install Excel COM Add-In with Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, add-in

I am writing a powershell script to install add-ins to Excel. The issue is I can not find a way to install a COM add-in to excel via powershell. Do you have any sugegstions. I tried to add it under the registry but just got Module Errors.

Thanks.

Comment: Programmability libraries for Office ship with Office, not with PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I believe you need to have Excel installed on the computer. Then you can run the following command:

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
```

You might want to just look at the open source [dfinkle/ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) module.

Comment: Thanks,
I have excel installed I will see if I can work out how to install the COM add-in using this command. Thanks

Comment: Okay so this works great with .xla Add-Ins but not .dll com add-ins.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what that means, but hopefully I got you on the right track.